# To hide the input values with 'X' in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, reactive-programming

```
class InputChange extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { InputValue: '', }

  }
        <input  
            type='tel'
            spellCheck={false}
            value={this.state.InputValue}
             onKeyDown={(event) => this.keyHandler( event)}
          />


 keyHandler( event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof event.which == "undefined") ? event.keyCode : event.which;

            if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
                var num = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
                let totalVal = this.props.user + num
                this.props.user = totalVal //
                this.setState({ tdlValue: totalVal.replace(/\d/g, 'X') })

            }
            else if (charCode == 8) {

                this.props.user=this.props.user.slice(0, selStart) + this.props.user.slice(selEnd)
                    this.setState({ ssnValue: this.props.user.replace(/\d/g, 'X') })
            }

 }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    if (this.props.user.==nextProps.user){
      alert("updated");
      }
      }
```

**mY AIM:**

1)TO UPDATE prop value

2)To show state value(so that user can see X instead of his input)

**my issues:**

1) Can we use OnChange event instead of adding/deleting on Keydown so that dynamically prop value changes?

2) Can we do it with componentWillReceiveProps.

3)componentWillReceiveProps nor firing ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see this being a bit of a pain because you update a state value and it comes round to be the value of the input. why won't you use password field for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `componentWillReceiveProps`? Props should be immutable.

Comment: @FemiOni  I cannot use password as I cannot mask it with X ,instead i will get dot.

Comment: @Max do you have any suggestion for doing it other way, where I can change the input to string of ''X".

Comment: Where is the `user` prop coming from? Is it being passed down from another component or a redux store? Also, what does it represent? It looks like you are concating the input with the value of `user` and reassigning it.